# Calculate a list

Tags: python

I have a list of a calculation `['1','+','2','\*','3']`. How do I put it together and make it give a result like
`['1','+','2','\*','3] = 7`

I actually have a string that looks like this `"1+2*3"` but converted it to a list with for loop

```
str = "1+2*3"

new = []
for letter in str:
    new.append(letter)

print(new)
```

I tried using this where I don't need to convert to list

```
operators = {ast.Add: op.add, ast.Sub: op.sub, ast.Mult: op.mul,
             ast.Div: op.truediv, ast.Pow: op.pow, ast.BitXor: op.xor,
             ast.USub: op.neg}

def eval_expr(expr):
    return eval_(ast.parse(expr, mode='eval').body)

def eval_(node):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Num): # <number>
        return node.n
    elif isinstance(node, ast.BinOp): # <left> <operator> <right>
        return operators[type(node.op)](eval_(node.left), eval_(node.right))
    elif isinstance(node, ast.UnaryOp): # <operator> <operand> e.g., -1
        return operators[type(node.op)](eval_(node.operand))
    else:
        raise TypeError(node)
```

Which works fine but can only calculate numbers like `1+2` not `10+20`, only numbers with one number in it.

Comment: `eval(string)` or `eval("".join(new))`

Comment: FWIW: `new = list(str)`, does the same thing…

Answer (score 2):

Simply joining up the string and using `eval()` can do this for you!

Beware of calling `eval()` on unknown inputs as it can do *anything the interpreter can do* (meaning an attacker against a website, for example, may be able to trivially take it over and execute their own code); see also the notes on `ast.literal_eval()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

```py
>>> eval("1+2*3")
7
>>> _lst = ['1','+','2','*','3']
>>> eval("".join(_lst))
7
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider a 3rd party library like Sympy, which can evalaute even quite complex strings as equations and also give symbolic results (which are often more useful than a decimal one)

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> simplify("1+2*3")
7
>>> simplify("sin(2/3*pi)")
sqrt(3)/2
>>> simplify("sin(2/3*pi)").evalf()
0.866025403784439
```

Comment: Oh ok thank you so much!!